# Replace &nbsp (or 0xAO) with space in a string

Tags: go

I am parsing a HTML document using Go and the package `golang.org/x/net/html`. When I extract the text field in some nodes, I want to replace all occurrences of `&nbsp` with a simple space.

My googling revealed, that `&nbsp` is unicode `0xA0`, so I did:

```
strings.ReplaceAll(node.Data, "\xA0", " ")
```

But the resulting string seems to include some unkown bytes (when I print it, it prints `�`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Unicode code point 0xA0 is UTF-8 encoded to the bytes [0xc2, 0xa0], not the single byte 0xa0 as assumed in the question.

Use `"\u00a0"` to get the UTF-8 encoding of the non-breaking space.

```
strings.ReplaceAll(node.Data, "\u00a0", " ")
```